# trying to save a h1 text.event to a variable so when you type the first letter it saves

Tags: javascript, jquery

and then you can type the second keypress and so forth
so you can type you own name in the h1 or what every you want
or is the only way to do it via $("input") I don't want a textbox

```
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    $("h1").text(event.key);
    });
```

do I use a for loop to save the first letter into an array or         "keypress" + "text(event.key)" + "?
then add the second to indice 1?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $("h1").text(event.key).length; i++) {
      var textType = $("h1").text(event.key)
    });
```

thanks in advance, trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: Why not use an `<input>` and style it as an `<h1>`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the newest character on to whatever the text of the `h1` currently is.

```js
let firstLetter = "";

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    $("h1").text($("h1").text() + event.key);
    firstLetter = $("h1").text()[0];  // Save the first letter
    console.log(firstLetter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```